# Load Cursor for TextBox From Resources

Tags: c#, winforms, resources, cursor

I wanna Change Cursor for TextBox ..
After add Cursor in Resources , Get Erorr
This Is My Code

```
        private void frmJop_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ClearAndShow();
            txtDepartmentNo.Cursor = new Cursor(new MemoryStream(Properties.Resources.SearchCursors));

        }
```

Erorr

```
System.OutOfMemoryException: 'Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program.'
```

Stack Trace

```
       StackTrace  "   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IPersistStream.Load(IStream pstm)\r\n   at System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.LoadPicture(IStream stream)\r\n   at System.Windows.Forms.Cursor..ctor(Stream stream)\r\n   at PayRoll.Basis.frmJop.frmJop_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\\Users\\20101\\Desktop\\PayRoll\\PayRoll\\Basis\\frmJop.cs:line 195\r\n   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)\r\n   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()\r\n   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)\r\n   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()\r\n   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)\r\n   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)\r\n   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)\r\n   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)\r\n   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)\r\n   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)\r\n   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)\r\n   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)"   string
```

Comment: please provide full exception with the stacktrace.

Comment: thanks, please provide a content of `Properties.Resources.SearchCursors` and [confirm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.cursor.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_Cursor__ctor_System_IO_Stream_) that you taken it from `.cur` file, you may post it to the question in `base64` encoding. Also, please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) .

Comment: The easiest way to add a Cursor as an embedded resource it to `Add -> New Item` to the Project, choose the Cursor template; it will generate an empty BMP file. Drag your Cursor in Visual Studio, copy it and paste it over the new Cursor you created before. Set the HotSpot and save. You'll find the new Cursor in the Project Explorer tree. Select it and set `Build Action -> Embedded Resource` in its properties. Build the Project. To use it: `Cursor cursor = new Cursor(GetType(), "Cursor1.cur");`, where `Cursor1` is the name you assigned to the new Cursor.